# Value of a Sine-Like Infinite Product

Tags: closed-form, riemann-zeta, infinite-product, trigonometric-series

Does the following infinite product have a "nice" closed form?

$$
P = \prod_{k=2}^{\infty} \left(\left(1 - \frac{1}{k^2}\right)^\dfrac{(-1)^k}{k}\right)
$$

I know that without the power one could easily use the infinite sine product formula or if the kth root was the $k$th power, there wouldn't be too much difficulty, but I could not find anything on this stated product.

**Edit:**

Finding the natural log of this is easily shown to be equivalent to finding the sum:

$$
\ln(P) = S = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{k^2}\right)\right)
$$

**Edit**

By expanding the logarithm in the sum, one obtains:

$$
S = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\left(\ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{k}\right) + \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{k}\right)\right)\right)
$$

Using the Taylor series for the natural logarithm, switching the order of summation, and then re-summing gives that the sum must be:

$$
S = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\eta \ (k+1)-1}{k}\right)+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(-1)^k(\eta \ (k+1)-1)}{k}\right)
$$

Which may then be expanded to the sums:

$$
S = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\zeta \ (k+1)-1}{k}\right)+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(-1)^k(\zeta \ (k+1)-1)}{k}\right)+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\zeta \ (k+1)}{k \ 2^k}\right)+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(-1)^k\zeta \ (k+1)}{k \ 2^k}\right)
$$

The first sum is the Lüroth or Alladi-Grinstead constant, and the rest don't seem to have well behaved closed forms. I don't know if things might cancel nicely and leave a decent solution. I doubt they leave a closed form.

Comment: By taking the logarithm you get instead an infinite sum that looks slightly easier to handle.

Comment: I came from the sum which had been the sum of logarithms that looked messy, and left no easily visible solution.

Comment: In general, the theory of infinite sums is much better developed than that of infinite products, especially through its connection with integrals. Therefore, transforming an infinite sum into a product is unlikely to make it easier to solve.

Comment: If you find an answer, please post it! Been working on this off and on most of the day

Comment: $\color{red}{(n+1)}=(k+1)$?

Comment: Yep. I'll fix that!